# How to secure data on a Chrome Packaged app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am building a Chrome App for my company's customers. These customers act as service providers (call them **service providers**) and have their own users (call them **end-users**) who share critical data with the customers. The app that I am building will be used by employees of my customers (call them **agents**). This app will handle critical data of the end-users which the service provider manages.

Though the service provider employs his/her agents and has certain degree of control, from my standpoint, I cannot trust the agents beyond a point. I want my app to provide security for the data that will be handled by the app.

I am using filesystem API and indexedDB API in my chrome app. The data stored using these is visible using the web development console (right click -> Inspect Element *OR* right click -> Inspect Background Page).

To ensure that agents cannot access the data, I want to disable the Web Development tools for the packaged app when it gets distributed. However I find no such API or mention of protection of this data. Is it possible? If yes, then how and if not, what are my alternatives?

I understand that taking the screenshot is still possible and that advanced users can probably go look for the actual data files on system's disks, so please do not mention these points. These agents are entry-level operators (mostly) and I want the data to be as secure as possible (and extra pointers are welcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to completely and securely disable inspect. `chrome://inspect` apparently currently works even if enterprise policy lockdown is in effect, if I'm remembering correctly (which is a bug of course). By the way, when an app is deployed / loaded as packed as opposed to loading it for development, easy access to Dev Tools is disabled by default.

Worst case scenario, all client-side data is to be considered compromised. To be secure, you need to keep the data on a central, well-protected server, have a robust auth system and give the data out on a need-to-know basis (implement some form of ACLs?).

You can deter casual attacks by encrypting data with a [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) module, but in the end you're just obfuscating the encryption code. A determined attacker can break the native code module and decrypt the data.

But *seriously* if all it takes to defeat your data protection is a screenshot, consider that a piece of paper and a pencil will do too. You're worrying too much in the wrong places.

*Also, [here are some pointers](https://xkcd.com/138/).*

Comment: I have an auth system in place and data is synced to server regularly.

About the Native Client module - seriously, 4 months in and I hadn't looked into this thing! Thanks for linking me there. And I'm not worried about someone disassembling a native module.

Again, not worried about screenshots or paper and pencil. I'm not that paranoid.

Most importantly: I got these - FAAADDAA4C128A7A, D9CB4A0111ADFEDE and 9876543210FEDCBA at those pointers. Help me understand them. ;) 

Thanks for the answer :)